# Click on a TextView opens new activity and jumps to a specific id

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I have an activity with a `TextView` that has an `onClick` function. 
After I click the `TextView` it should open a new activity and jump to a specific `id`(of e.g. another `TextView`) in the newly opened activity. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Can you define jumping to a specific id in a mobile context?

Comment: what do you mean "by jumping to an id" ?.. Are you asking about setting focus to a text view?

Comment: Yes, setting focus what I wanted. P.S. The TextView is in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
            scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, some_random_view_id.getTop());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `TextView` and other elements inside a `ScrollView` and then you can use `scrollTo(int x, int y)` method of `ScrollView` to jump to the location of a specific element. You will need to find out the position of that specific element first.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCLick` callback use an Intent to launch a new `Activity`. If necessary use the putExtra method on the Intent to add additional information, e.g. the `TextView` to "highlight".

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("TEXT_VIEW_ID", id);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the `onCreate()` method of NewActivity possibly use `findViewById` to get the `TextView` you need and then call `requestFocus` on it.