# How to open a new activity and scroll to specific child view?

Tags: android, listview

Dear StackOverflow community, could I ask for some help?

I’m a very amateur coder, trying to develop an app version of a reference document, and it needs to be searchable. I can’t get the search results to link back to the document activity and scroll down to the target text.

I’ve got a MainActivity displaying  the document in a scrollview within a co-ordinator layout, so I can use the floating action button.  At the top of the content_main layout I created buttons that will scroll down to specific child views (section headings)  of the scrollview using smoothScrollTo. They work fine.

But the document needs to be searchable. I created an ArrayList that gives search results in a listview (from an example in www.androidhive.com), in an activity named SearchActivity. I’m trying to work out how to use clicks on listview search results to open the content_main layout and scroll down to a specific child view. 
I’ve tried the approaches suggested in SO  ([Click on a TextView opens new activity and jumps to a specific id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633829/click-on-a-textview-opens-new-activity-and-jumps-to-a-specific-id) ;  [Android New Intent start particular method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876043/android-new-intent-start-particular-method/7876643#7876643) )  and neither have worked. I can’t find anything else online that gives me any idea how to manage it.  Can anyone suggest a way?  Here is one way I tried. This opens the activity, but doesn’t scroll.

I'd be grateful for any help.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 


Button buttonHeader3a, buttonHeader3b, buttonHeader3c, buttonHeader3d; 
ScrollView myView; 

TextView myTV; 
TextView hdr3a, hdr3b, hdr3c, hdr3d; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab); 
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

@Override 
       public void onClick(View v) { 
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class); 
       startActivity(i); 
        } 
    }); 


    buttonHeader3a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1); 
    buttonHeader3b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2); 
    buttonHeader3c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3); 
    buttonHeader3d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4); 

    myView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myview); 
    myTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ch3p16); 

    hdr3a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header3a);   //hdr = header 
    hdr3b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header3b); 
    hdr3c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header3c); 
    hdr3d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header3d); 


    buttonHeader3a.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 


        public final void onClick(View view) { 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3a.getTop()); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    }); 

    buttonHeader3b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {   

        public final void onClick(View view) { 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3b.getTop()); 
                } 
            }); 
        }
    }); 

    buttonHeader3c.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 

        public final void onClick(View view) { 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3c.getTop()); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    }); 


    buttonHeader3d.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 


        public final void onClick(View view) { 
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() { 
                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3d.getTop()); 
                } 
            }); 
        } 
    }); 
} 

    public void onButtonLinkPrealerting (View v) { 
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonLinkPrealerting) { 
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chapter4.class); 
            startActivity(i); 
        } 
    } 

@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); 
    return true; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will 
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long 
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. 
    int id = item.getItemId(); 

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement 
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) { 
        return true; 
    } 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
} 


// Here's where i'm trying to pick up an intent in SearchActivity and scroll down 


@Override 
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) { 
    super.onNewIntent (intent); 
    if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("myMethod")) { 
        myView.post(new Runnable() { 
            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3a.getTop()); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
} 

// similar methods to scroll to other sections...
```

}

SearchActivity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {


// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;


// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


    // Listview Data
    String products[] = {
            "first very long string",
            "second very long string",
    // Several other very long strings
            };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            SearchActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(
       new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     String a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();


     if (a.equals"first very long string"))
      {
      Intent intent = new Intent ();
      intent.setClass (getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("methodName", "myMethod");
      startActivity(intent);
                                 }

      else

      if (a.equals"second very long string"))

 // more of the same

          }
          });
          }
          }
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would move the logic of your `onNewIntent` (in MainActivity) into the `onCreate` instead.

According to the documentation,

> Handle onNewIntent() to inform the fragment manager that the
>        state is not saved.  If you are handling new intents and may be
>        making changes to the fragment state, you want to be sure to call
>        through to the super-class here first.  Otherwise, if your state
>        is saved but the activity is not stopped, you could get an
>        onNewIntent() call which happens before onResume() and trying to
>        perform fragment operations at that point will throw IllegalStateException
>        because the fragment manager thinks the state is still saved.

Therefore, simply check whether you have data passed to your activity onCreate when creating it :

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    //All your other initialisations

    //Get any potential intent that was passed to the activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
      //Is there a string extra in that intent?
      String extra = intent.getStringExtra("methodName");
      //Is that string not empty and equals what you're looking for?
      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(extra) && extra.equals("myMethod")) {
        myView.post(new Runnable() { 
          @Override 
          public void run() { 
              myView.smoothScrollTo(0, hdr3a.getTop()); 
          } 
        }); 
      }
  }
}
```